# How do I send a binary attachment in an email with Java using the JavaMail API?

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

Using JDK1.5 how does one send a binary attachemnt (such as a PDF file) easily using the JavaMail API?

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [JavaMail FAQ](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/FAQ.html)? It seems to have little snippets to demonstrate the process (and how to fix a common problem -- running out of memory).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you don't want to read some links and don't want any external dependencies, you need to use MimeMultipart and BodyPart:

```java
MimeMultipart messageContent = new MimeMultipart();

BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
DataSource source = new FileDataSource(yourFile);
bodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
bodyPart.setFileName("MyFile.ext");
bodyPart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);

// Then add to your message:
messageContent.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
```

Attaching a body to the messages is just attaching a BodyPart with disposition Part.INLINE

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it easily I'd suggest using [Commons-Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/)! It's built on the JavaMail API, but it makes it much simpler.

There is a sample in the [User Guide](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html) on how to send email with attachments... it's much easier than using the standard JavaMail API!